# How to secure WCF Web Services?

Tags: wcf, security

I have a service which has a method :

UserProfile GetUserProfile(int userId);

Here user which has a profile can get its profile on the client. But here the problem is any user who connects to the web service and plugs in the ANY user id gets the profile of that particular user. How do i prevent this?

I'm using Facebook Authentication (If that helps you answer this)

Please do help.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions and add the userId to your session variables. The GetUserProfile() should then return the profile of the userid that is stored in the current session.